How to understand if server have inough resoruces and solve database out of memery problem?
Hi friends for many years i used ISP manager for hosging 7 websites and never had any problems. But this year i migratet to newer softare and server and server few times per feek have database out of memory accidents.
grep "Killed process" /var/log/syslog

Sep 30 05:23:30 isp2024 kernel: [418150.256304] Out of memory: Killed process 1023 (mysqld) total-vm:1373168kB, anon-rss:713040kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:999 pgtables:1820kB oom_score_adj:0
Sometimes but more less server procesor is overloaded.
I use vps on google cloud with 1 vCPU and 5,7 gb of RAM. during noramal days server load is not huge. During work days procesor is loaded up to 35% and and used ram is about 25%.
Mostly problems is when many crowlers and bots starts to crowl server,
I used robots txt to block most bad bots and crowlers. I put server behind cloudflare free account. I enabled built in ISP manager dos protection and set strict limits. Blocked many ip adreses. Realy do not know what to do. So Do i need pay more so different bots can crowl server?
Can you give me some advice?
So i have other server with cyperpanel with 10 websites and it never had any problems.
